# Remove oracle home base in windows

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

How to manually remove multiple the oracle home base in windows inorder to start with a fresh install of oracle server. I had unsuccessful attempts in deleting it using the Universal Installer as it says remove from the command-line.

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/about) is more helpful for this kind of question

Comment: Then go to uninstall and run uninstaller manually.

Comment: You are supposed to run ORACLE_HOME\deinstall\deinstall.bat

Comment: Check also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: @Rene, obviously that is what TO tried but without success.

Comment: yes obviously...

Answer (score 0):

PART 1

FIRST YOU NEED TO GO TO THIS FILE 
c:\oracle\10.0...
or just look for the file name

PART 2

click on computer right click and click manage >>>> local users and groups >>>> users >>>> right click on `oracle` (or other name {it all about what you made}) >>>> select delete

part 3

go the install folder and delete the last flies (just right click and delete)

ohh and if you need more info ask me :-D i will love to help

Answer (score -1):

Just check out that URL & then follow Oracle deInstall process from your windows
[Click Here](https://docs.oracle.com/html/B10131_02/deinstall.htm)